# Unexpected behavior in authoryear-comp (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex

I'm a reasonably experienced XeLaTeX + BibTeX + natbib user trying to transition to using biblatex.

I want to generate a citation label such as "(Doe et al. 2001a,b, 2002)" despite the fact that the three entries all have distinct (unique) lists of authors. So far, using MacTeX-2011, the best I can get is "(Doe et al. 2001a; Doe et al. 2001b; Doe et al. 2002)".

Any ideas how I could achieve that? I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Please note that I'm asking how it might be done, rather than whether it should be done at all. I understand that you might not like this citing convention.

Here is my source file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}

@article{doe2001a,
title = {foo},
year = {2001},
author = {J. Doe and R. Smith},
journal = {Nature}
}

@article{doe2001b,
title = {bar},
year = {2001},
author = {J. Doe and B. Dylan},
journal = {Science}
}

@article{doe2002,
title = {foobar},
year = {2002},
author = {J. Doe and B. Dylan and R. Smith},
journal = {WSJ}
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[%
  style=authoryear-comp,
  backend=biber,
  maxbibnames=99,
  maxnames=1,
  uniquelist=false,
  uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\parencite{doe2001a,doe2001b,doe2002}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example gives for me – with MacTeX 2011 and biblatex 1.6 – “(Doe et al. 2001a,b, 2002)”. Which biblatex version are you using?

Comment: Wow. That was easy.I upgraded biblatex from 1.5 to 1.6 and voilà. Thanks, domwass!

Comment: I suggest one of you post an answer to the question so that we can close the topic. The answer being: this behaviour had been fixed in biblatex 1.6 version.

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour has been fixed in version 1.6 of biblatex.